# How to clear console(terminal) with sqlcmd in sql server(mssql) command-line client on Windows?

Tags: sql-server, windows, terminal, command-line, sqlcmd

With **SQLite command** below, I could clear console(terminal) in **sqlite3 command-line client** on **Windows**:

```
sqlite>.shell cls
```

But, with **sqlcmd**, I couldn't find how to clear console(terminal) in **sql server(mssql) command-line client** on **Windows** even though I googled about it.

```
1>
```

So, with **sqlcmd**, are there any ways to clear console(terminal) in **sql server(mssql) command-line client** on **Windows**?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is the only way on Windows

```
CTRL + C
cls
sqlcmd -S SERVER\INSTANCE
```